# How to use pixi.js to export an image with a background color?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I do this.

```
...
this.app = new PIXI.Application({
            width: this.options.width,
            height: this.options.height,
            resolution: 1,
            antialias: true,
            // forceCanvas: true,
        });
this.app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xeef1f0;
...
...
this.app.renderer.plugins.extract.image(this.app.stage, 'image/jpeg', 1))
...
```

and I get a picture with no background color。

What can I do to get a picture with a background color？

Answer (score 0):

```
this.app = new PIXI.Application({
    ...
    backgroundColor: 0xeef1f0
});
```

https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Application.html

Comment: Note this only works when `preserveDrawingBuffer` is enabled; otherwise, Pixi's `extract` does not include the WebGL clear color.